# Problema con animación de borde de una imagen

Tags: html, css, html5, animación

Estoy haciendo una *border* animado con CSS que aparece de arriba hacia abajo y el problema que tengo es que la parte superior y derecha aparecen detrás de la imagen, mientras que la parte inferior e izquierda delante de la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podria hacer para que tanto la superior como la parte derecha aparezcan adelante de la imagen?

```css
/*****CSS*******/
.hovereffect {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.hovereffect::before, .hovereffect::after {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.hovereffect::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top-color: #F87600;
  border-right-color: #F87600;
  animation: border 2s infinite;
}

.hovereffect::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: border 2s 1s infinite, borderColor 2s 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes border {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  25% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes borderColor {
  0% {
    border-bottom-color: #F87600;
    border-left-color: #F87600;
  }
  50% {
    border-bottom-color: #F87600;
    border-left-color: #F87600;
  }
  51% {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hovereffect">   
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Creo que lo que pasa es lo siguiente: cuando se renderizan en pantalla los componentes, el orden de posicionamiento es el mismo orden de la jerarquía, por tanto se aparece el div y luego la imagen... pero puesto que el el div tiene un pseudo-elemento "antes" (`:before`), ese elemento está por detrás, mientras que el pseudo-elemento "después" (:`after`) acaba por encima.

La solución es jugar con el z-index, por ejemplo añadiendo `z-index: -1` a la imagen, para que los bordes estén por encima

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplemente es ponerle un `z-index` a `::before` y `::after` junto con la posición absoluta.

Además como una opción mejorada, el contenedor padre `hovereffect` debe tener las medidas fijas y no la imágen (la imágen debe ser 100%). Porque todo está en el padre.

```css
/*****CSS*******/
.hovereffect {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.hovereffect::before, .hovereffect::after {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.hovereffect::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top-color: #F87600;
  border-right-color: #F87600;
  animation: border 2s infinite;
}

.hovereffect::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: border 2s 1s infinite, borderColor 2s 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes border {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  25% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes borderColor {
  0% {
    border-bottom-color: #F87600;
    border-left-color: #F87600;
  }
  50% {
    border-bottom-color: #F87600;
    border-left-color: #F87600;
  }
  51% {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hovereffect">   
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Tú has aumentado el z-index de los bordes, yo he disminuido el de la imagen. No me di cuenta de tu respuesta mientras miraba el [comportamiento sin z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index) para añadir mi comentario. Borraré mi respuesta y dejaré la explicación como comentario

Comment: Si @PabloLozano el trabajo es con el **before** y **after** y a estos es que se debe. Esta bien